# How to tell when suggested edits have been considered?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

If I make an edit to a post or answer, how will I know whether the edit has been accepted? I understand that all edits are placed in a queue, but I am not sure how to tell if the edit has made its way through the queue or not.

Answer (score 5):

Have you already suggested some edits? I don't see any on your [activity tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/48827/alexey-volkov?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

I think that if someone has suggested edits then he can see them in his activity tab, as, for example, [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18798/simon-hayward?tab=activity). Notice that you can click on the text *suggested edit* and you will get to the page showing the suggested edit, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32369). On that page you can see what happened with the suggested edit so far - which user voted to approve the edit, which users voted to reject the edit or whether some action has been taken at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get +2 reputation, when your suggestion is accepted, and (I think) a notification. 
When your edit is accepted it also shows up that you edited that post.